# how to get a list of posts by label chosen by option botton

Tags: javascript, list, label, html-select

i got this code that make a search in the blog by titles.
**how to show a list of the post titles that chosen there.**

```
...<option>
</option></select>
<input onclick="getValue()" type="button" value="סנן" />
</div>...

<script type="text/javascript">
function getValue()
{var 
valcmbarea=document.getElementById("אזור").value;
valcmbSidebar=document.getElementById("1נושא").value;
valcmbSidebar2=document.getElementById("2נושא").value;
valOutput=(valcmbarea+valcmbSidebar+valcmbSidebar2);
}
</script>
```